# Powershell Switch-Statement doesn't change value

Tags: windows, powershell, switch-statement

This is the Powershell script I wrote:

```
$varCompList = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*Name of Computers*'" -Properties OperatingSystemVersion | select DNSHostName, OperatingSystemVersion
foreach ($System in $varCompList){
    $Restult=switch ($System.OperatingSystemVersion){
        "10.0 (20348)"{"Server 2022"}
        "10.0 (19042)"{"Server 2019 20H2"}
        "10.0 (18363)"{"Server 2019 1909"}
        "10.0 (17763)"{"Server 2019 1809"}
        "10.0 (14393)"{"Server 2016"}
    }
}
echo $varCompList
```

It displays all the Servers like it should but the `OperatingSystemVersion` is still displayed as **10.0 (14393)**.

What am I missing?

Comment: `$Restult` is assigned but never used, later only `$varCompList` is printed. Is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: I know that `$Result` isn't used but I have no idea where to put it. If I `echo` the `$Result`, it'll only show the version of my own PC/Server this script runs on. I'd somehow have to combine those.

Comment: Replace `$Restult=` with `$System.OperatingSystemVersion=`

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen Write this as an answer, if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently assigning the mapped OS names to a variable, but you never use it for anything and you never update the original input object.

Instead of assigning the result to a variable, assign it to the `OperatingSystemVersion` property on each object instead:

```
foreach ($System in $varCompList){
    $System.OperatingSystemVersion = switch ($System.OperatingSystemVersion){
        "10.0 (20348)"{"Server 2022"}
        "10.0 (19042)"{"Server 2019 20H2"}
        "10.0 (18363)"{"Server 2019 1909"}
        "10.0 (17763)"{"Server 2019 1809"}
        "10.0 (14393)"{"Server 2016"}
        default { $_ }
    }
}
```

The `default` case will ensure you preserve the original version string for any computer that doesn't have any of the listed versions installed.